# onClick event buttons

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have 5 buttons,each of them open another activity. How to make clickeble only one of them at current moment?When i click 2 different buttons simultaneusly onClick event calls 2 times and 2 different activities opens. How can i resolve my problem. Thanks.My code

```
public void onClick(View v)
     {
            switch (v.getId()) 
            {
            case R.id.play_button:
                onPlayClick();
                setButtonsEnable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.difficalty_button:
                onDifficultyClick();
                setButtonsEnable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.hight_scores_button:
                onHighScoresClick();
                setButtonsEnable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.share_button:
                setButtonsEnable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.turn_off_button:
                onLeaderboardClick();
                setButtonsEnable(false);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
    }
```

After return to main activity i make my buttons clickable

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setButtonsEnable(true);
}

public void setButtonsEnable(boolean config) 
{
    playBtn.setClickable(config);
    difficultyBtn.setClickable(config);
    hScoreBtn.setClickable(config);
    shareBtn.setClickable(config);
    turnOffButton.setClickable(config);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setOnClickListener(null)
```

would do the trick or you can make

```
setClickable(false)
```

Comment: when i do setClickable(false) instead of setEnabled(false) the result is the same.

Comment: try to use null value on setClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you really need is RadioGroup? It allows out of the box to select click/select only one button at the time.

[Doc reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable clicked in `Activity`:

```
boolean clicked=false;
```

Set this value in onClick code:

```
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
       if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.play_button:
            onPlayClick();
            setButtonsEnable(false);
            break;
        case R.id.difficalty_button:
            onDifficultyClick();
            setButtonsEnable(false);
            break;
        case R.id.hight_scores_button:
            onHighScoresClick();
            setButtonsEnable(false);
            break;
        case R.id.share_button:
            setButtonsEnable(false);
            break;
        case R.id.turn_off_button:
            onLeaderboardClick();
            setButtonsEnable(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }}
}
```

Comment: And what this code should do?) It will catch onClick event only from play button.

Comment: i thought this is what you wanted. Let me edit my ans.

Comment: This should work, but don't think that is the best way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an activity on each click, use a onclicklistener for each button or add a method call in the xml layout via `android:onClick="someMethod"`, when you click a button and call another activity the UI should block itself...have you tried it this way?